# Python: Concatenating strings in a list with each other

Tags: python, list, io

I have a text file of 1000 words each on an individual line, and I want to create a text file of 'phrases' by concatenating each of these words together with one another with no spaces in between, up to phrases of four words maximum and with no repeat words.

**For example:**

Input (each item is a line on a txt file):

```
["good", "morning", "america"]
```

Output (same format as input):

```
["good", "morning", "america", "goodmorning", "morninggood", "goodamerica", "americagood", "morningamerica", "americamorning", "goodmorningamerica", "goodamericamorning", "morninggoodamerica", "morningamericagood", "americagoodmorning", "americamorninggood"]
```

I'm a bit new to Python, so my first instinct was to open the file with open(,r), use .readlines() to put it in a list,  run four nested loops (each with 1000 runs) and concatenate them all together in a new list, and then write that list to a file line-by-line using open(,w) and another for loop. But I am concerned about the feasibility and time consumption of so many for loops.

Is there any way to optimize this operation to implement it better or make it run faster? Thanks!

Comment: It not really clear what you are trying to do. Maybe show us an example list of 10 words and the desired output from that list.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I've added an example to try to clarify my question a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Maybe the `itertools.permutations` function could be useful to solve this problem. You can find its docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
words=["a","b","c","d"]

result=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    result.extend(list(permutations(words,i)))


phrases=[]
for e in result:
    phrases.append("".join(e))
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote some similar code, and it worked for permutations up to 3, but when I got to the permutations() with four items, I received a Killed:9 error. Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: Are you closing the file after getting words and then doing permutations? Because it seems like you are running out of memory.    And try to write the output directly in the output file and not store it in the list to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(writes output to file):

```
from itertools import permutations 
MAX_LEN = 4
def get_sets(items): 
    for i in range(0,len(items)+1): 
        for element in permutations(items,i): 
            if len(element) <= MAX_LEN:
                yield (''.join(element)) 

items=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e']
with open('out.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for elem in get_sets(items):
        fh.write(elem)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote some similar code, and it worked for permutations up to 3, but when I got to the permutations() with four items, I received a Killed:9 error. Is there a way I can avoid that?